# Was Steve Kenson involved in the design of Mutants & Masterminds 3e?

Tags: history-of-gaming, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, mutants-and-masterminds

I was talking to a group of gaming friends and the topic of Green Ronin and [Steve Kenson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Kenson) came up. Someone commented that Steve Kenson was working on *Aberrant* and didn't seem to do anything for Green Ronin anymore. I commented that it seemed he'd branched off into *Icons* years before that, and that I wasn't certain whether he'd even worked on the third edition of *Mutants and Masterminds*. He of course wrote the first and second editions, and he's credited for "writing and design" in the 3e *Heroes Handbook*, but I remember he more or less dropped off the Atomic Think Tank at the time, and we had a new line designer shortly after the edition's release. Since a lot of the 3e text was slightly changed text from 2e, it struck me that they might be crediting his previous work on the system and/or making use of his name to add legitimacy to the new edition.

So, was Steve Kenson substantially involved in the development of Third Edition?

Comment: Sidenote: in terms of copyright (if this wouldn't be a work for hire for the publisher), only touching up the text would not be an alteration in the amount needed to warrant it as being a transformation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### TL;DR, Yes

[Steve Kenson replied on December 3rd](https://twitter.com/SKenson/status/1201840596777877504):

> I did most of the design work on M&M 3e/DC Adventures, in collaboration with developer Jon Leitheusser.